# Node Docker Container pipeline in Jenkins not finding external shell file

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins to run a pipeline build inside a Docker container. I am having problems getting it to run an external shell file that I have comitted to the repo. The `Jenkins` file below is what I am using and I get the following error:

```
+ ./jenkins/scripts/test.sh

/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/alpine-react-frontend_develop@2@tmp/durable-13806bdf/script.sh: line 1: ./jenkins/scripts/test.sh: not found

script returned exit code 127
```

The strange part is that I can see the file in the output of the `ls -lhart` commands.

```
+ ls -lhart jenkins/scripts/

total 12

drwxr-x---    3 999      1002        4.0K Nov 26 20:34 ..

-rwxr-x--x    1 999      1002          87 Nov 27 15:26 test.sh

drwxr-x---    2 999      1002        4.0K Nov 27 15:26 .
```

If I don't run the `chmod +x` command before trying to execute the file I get a permission denied error. Does anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

EDIT:
It seems I am on to something. I found this ticket https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50902 It seems like if you have the shebang `#!` inside of your shell file then it can't use relative paths. I removed the shebang and the script started to execute but had a problem parsing my commands that took arguments in the file.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:6-alpine'
    }

  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'Hi'
      }
    }

    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'chmod +x ./jenkins/scripts/test.sh'
        sh 'ls -lhart'
        sh 'ls -lhart jenkins/scripts/'
        sh './jenkins/scripts/test.sh'
      }
    }

  }
  environment {
    CI = 'true'
    HOME = '.'
  }
}
```